# Why do I need to write \\d instead of \d in a C++ regex?

Tags: regex

I'mm starting to learn about Regular Expressions and I have written code in c++
my task is : Implement a function that replaces each digit in the given string with a `'@'` character.

For my example, the `input`string = `"12 points"`.

I know I need to use `\d` for matches a digit. I tried to use this : `std::regex_replace(input,std::regex("\d"),"@");`
but it is not working: the `output` is still `"12 points"`;

Then I searched the internet and the result is:
`std::regex_replace(input,std::regex("\\d"),"@");`
with the `output` is `"@@ points"`.

Can anyone help me to understand what is `"\\d"` ?

Comment: Thrre is no need to use two backslashes. Use a raw string literal, `R"(\d)"`. The backslash here will be a literal backslash, just what is needed  to create a regex escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d` means decimal, however, in the regular expression, the `\` is a special character, which needs to be escaped on its own as well, hence in `\\d` you escape the `\` to mark it to be used as a regular character instead of its special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

When you use "\d" in a C++ application, the \ is an escape character in C++. So it doesn't treat the following d as a d.

Regex then gets a string that doesn't have \d in it, but most likely an empty string (since \d doesn't evaluate to anything in C++ to my knowledge).

When you use "\d" you are escaping the . So C++ reads the string as "\d" as you intended.

An example of when you'd use an escape character, is when you want to output a quote. "\"" would output a single double quote.